# relationship between Solovay–Strassen and Miller-Rabin primality tests

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

I'm studying relationship between Solovay–Strassen and Miller-Rabin  primality tests. I suppose that if number $a$ satisfies Miller-Rabin test for number $N$ ($N$ is odd number) then $a$ satisfies Solovay–Strassen test.  But I have some problems with proof it.  I proved it for $N = 4n-1$, but if $N = 4n+1$ my method doesn't work. I have some ideas aboit it. For example, if following assumption is true I'll be able to solve  general task.

Assumption: if $ a^{\frac{N-1}{2}} \equiv \pm 1 ~ \text{mod}(N) $, then $ a^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \equiv \pm 1 $, when $p$ - prime divisor of $N$, $p \equiv N \equiv 1 ~ \text{mod}(4) $

I'll be glad to see proof or refutation of my assumption. I would also like to know.  Is my assumption about relationship between Solovay–Strassen and Miller-Rabin  primality tests  true?

Comment: What do you mean with "simple divisor" ? I only know that Miller Rabin gives a much higher probability that a number passing is actually prime, if the same number of bases is used.

Comment: @Peter , I'm sorry, I mean "prime divisor". I want to show that if number N pass  Miller-Rabin test  with base = a then N pass  Solovay–Strassen test

Comment: Have you searched for a number passing Miller Rabin but not Solovay - Strassen ?

Comment: @Peter, yes ( but I supposed that there are no such numbers)

Comment: I know Miller Rabin very well, but Solovay-Strassen only slightly. If I remember right, Euler's criterion is the key for this test, right ?

Comment: @Peter, yes  Solovay-Strasse test use Jacobi Symbol. This function bases on Legendre symbol. It links with  Euler's criterion

Comment: Do you have an answer for this yet?